# Open downloaded file using intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent, kotlin

I make a retrofit call to my own API that provides me a list of files with the following content:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Example_file.jpg",
    "ext": "jpg",
    "b64": "data in base 64 format"
  }
]
```

I show this list of files using a recycler view. When I click on one element from recycler view, I decode the base64 content and generate a file like the following:

```
val content = Base64.getDecoder().decode(file.getB64()!!.toByteArray())
val os = FileOutputStream(getExternalStorageDirectory().path + file.getName(), true)
os.write(content)
os.flush()
os.close()
```

After this is complete, I would like to open this file using the Android file manager.

How can I force to open that stored file?

Comment: "I make a retrofit call to my own API that provides me a list of files with the following content" -- I *strongly* recommend that you revise your Web service, so you can download the files individually and directly. That will consume less bandwidth and make it much less likely that your app will fail with an `OutOfMemoryError`. "I would like to open this file using the Android file manager, because I can receive a pdf, jpeg, txt." -- what does this mean? A user uses a file manager; an app does not.

Answer (score 3):

If you meant opening by the default file opener for that file type you can use the method below.

*[I found this solution on this site a long ago, I don't have the original link to that answer]*

```
public void openFile(File file, Context context) {

    Uri url = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/msword");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/pdf");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/x-wav");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/rtf");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "audio/x-wav");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "image/gif");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "image/jpeg");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "text/plain");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "video/*");
    } else {
        //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file
        //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
        //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
        //so you can choose which application to use
        intent.setDataAndType(url, "*/*");
    }

    try {
        if (file.exists())
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open"));
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "File is corrupted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Application is found to open this file.\nThe File is saved at" + Constant.DIRECTORY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```